# Expression is not assignable on strlen(string)

Tags: c

I keep getting this error when trying to cut out all repeating characters:

```
solution.c:16:26: error: expression is not assignable
        (int)strlen(str1)--; 
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

I am trying to do a program to check if a given string of scrambled characters could be rearranged into a given word. Link to Codewars Kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/train/c.

My full code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool scramble(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  /* solution here */
  bool indicator = false;
  for(int i=0; i<(int)strlen(str1); i++){
    char ch = str1[i];
    for(int j=i+1; j<(int)strlen(str1); ){      
      if(str1[i] == str1[j]){
        for(int k=j; k<(int)strlen(str1); k++){
          str1[k] = str1[k+1];
        }
        (int)strlen(str1)--; 
      } else {
          j++;
      }
    } 
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(str2); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (int)strlen(str1); j++) {
      if (str1[j] == str2[i]) {
        indicator = true;
      }
    }
    if (indicator == true) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  //printf("%d\n", indicator);
  if (indicator == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

In order for me to complete this problem I have to shorten the string and remove all repeating characters from the scrambled string. How can I solve this issue, or if I can't at all, then how can I shorten the string after a char removal?

Comment: `strlen(str1)--` That in no way shortens the string. And you can't apply that operator on a function return value. To shorten a string you need to NUL out the last character. `str1[strlen(str1)-1]='\0';` (I haven't fully followed your code logic so can't confirm whether you actually do mean "shorten" in that sense).

Comment: What variable are you trying to decrease in `(int)strlen(str1)--;` ?

Comment: What exactly you expect `(int)strlen(str1)--` to do?

Comment: I am trying to decrease str1. Also could you please show me how to NUL out the last character? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I expect (int)strlen(str1)-- to shorten the string.

Comment: So you just invented a syntax for that and expecting it to work? The first comment is giving one way to do it.

Comment: Ok, like @kaylum mentioned, that's not how you do it. `strlen` returns the length of the string and decreasing that number does not change the string in any way.

Comment: (int)strlen(str1)-- is just a placeholder for what i want to do.

Comment: Think of it this way: if you write a factorial function then do you expect `factorial(n) = factorial(n) / n;` to decrease n by 1? Functions only go one way: the computer calculates the factorial and then changing the factorial doesn't change the original number (in fact the compiler knows this won't work so it won't let you). And counting the length of a string and then changing the counter doesn't actually make the string shorter (and the compiler knows this won't work so it won't let you).

Comment: "*just a placeholder*". So why are you asking about an error in "pretend" code? Better just to ask "how to shorten a string" directly if that is indeed what you don't know how to do.

Comment: `strlen` is a function that rescans the argument string each time, looking for 0x00. It is _not_ an "attribute" as in some languages such as perl/python. So, if you use it as part of the test clause of a `for` loop, it increases the execution time of the `for` loop from O(n) to O(n^2). So, better is (e.g) `for (int i = 0;  str1[i] != 0;  ++i)` To strip newline: `str1[strcspn(str1,"\n")] = 0;`

Comment: `if (indicator)` is enough to check for `true`. Why not just `return indicator;` instead of 5 lines in last statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the last character:

```
if(*str)
{
   str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0;
}
```

`if` is needed to handle strings having `0` length, which cannot be shortened

```
str[strlen(str) - !!*str] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I didn't analyze your code :-)

However, you are working on so-called "C-strings", which are just sequences of characters with a terminating 0 after the last character of the string (that's a binary 0, not the character "0").

These strings are not "objects" of any kind; "strlen", in particular, is not a property or something like that -- it's a function that just counts the characters until it hits the 0.

```
(int)strlen(str1)--;
```

basically attempts to reduce a non-existent variable by one -- so that can't work.
Besides, as I've just explained, adding or subtracting anything from the result of strlen() doesn't do anything. It's just a computed number.

Instead, when you change the string data, you have to make sure that the terminating 0 ends up in the correct place -- that's the "end of string" marker. Since strlen() is just counting up until it hits that 0, it will always return the correct length.

Depending on where the strings come from, you might not be able to change them at all; you will have to take appropiate precautions so these strings are writable, and if you're making them longer than before, you must allocate enough memory for them.

If that sounds like a lot detail-work -- that's correct. In 2022, we now have C++ and the "std::string" class, which usually makes things easier...

Comment: It doesn’t really make sense to suggest a C++ solution on a question that has the C tag.